# How to change barPosition of navigationBar to topAttached in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to change barPosition of navController's navBar to topAttached type. I try to use **position(for bar:)** method of UINavigationBarDelegate. In MyViewController class:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.delegate = self
```

and in extension:

```
extension MyViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate{
    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .topAttached
    }
}
```

But it's not working, because of

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'

So is here any else way to change barPosition in swift 3? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

`NavigationBar.position` is a `readonly` property. You can't change it. If you want to change the frames of Navigationbar. Firstly change the frames of UINavigationController and then bar in it.

Example:

If you want to shift it downwards:

```
    self.navigationController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 100.0, width: 320.0, height: 426.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 320.0, height: 44.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I don't need to change height of nav bar. I need to change exactly positionBar, but with same frame. Because when I move MyViewController(which subview of another controller), the positionBar changes in iOS 10, but it work correctly in iOS 9